# Doctrine query builder throws an error

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Im trying to write a simple query and then var dump the result. However I'm getting this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 15 near 'Admin WHERE name': Error:
>   Class 'Admin' is not defined.

This is my method:

```
public function processLogin()
{
    $name     = $this->request->request->get('username');
    $password = $this->request->request->get('password');

    $em    = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT id FROM Admin WHERE name = :name AND password = :password')
                ->setParameter('name', $name)
                ->setParameter('password', $password);

    $result = $query->getResult();
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Where could be the error?

Comment: Did you include the Entity class Admin with ``use YourBundle\Entity\Admin``? Also, where is this method located?

Comment: Did you try ``FROM YourBundle:Admin WHERE``?

Comment: Yeah that helped. I also added aliases in a few places. SELECT u.id FROM AppBundle:Admin u WHERE u.name = :name AND u.password = :password . Why do I need these aliases .u? What is the use of it?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your query as follows

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT u.id 
     FROM YourBundle:Admin u
     WHERE u.name = :name 
       AND 
           u.password = :password
     ')
     ->setParameter('name', $name)
     ->setParameter('password', $password);
```

The aliases part has something to do with the query builder. I think if you use the entity manager you don't have to do that much work.